# Using Evaluate with a Pure Function and SetDelayed

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to evaluate f below by passing a list to some function:

```
f = {z[1] z[2], z[2]^2};
a = % /. {z[1]-> #1,z[2]-> #2};
F[Z_] := Evaluate[a] & @@ Z ;
```

So now if I try `F[{1,2}]` I get `{2, 4}` as expected. But looking closer `?F` returns the definition

```
F[Z_] := (Evaluate[a] &) @@ Z
```

which depends on the value of `a`, so if we set `a=3` and then evaluate `F[{1,2}]`, we get `3`. I know that adding the last `&` makes the `Evaluate[a]` hold, but what is an elegant work around? Essentially I need to force the evaluation of `Evaluate[a]`, mainly to improve efficiency, as `a` is in fact quite complicated.

Can someone please help out, and take into consideration that `f` has to contain an `Array[z,2]` given by some unknown calculation. So writing

```
F[Z_] := {Z[[1]]Z[[2]],Z[[2]]^2}
```

would not be enough, I need this to be generated automatically from our `f`.

Many thanks for any contribution.

Comment: The "natural" way seems to pass everything as an argument to F[z_,fa_,fa_] (with convenient definitions). Is there any reason for not going that way?

Comment: Do you mean something like `F[Z_,f_]:= (f/.{z[1]-> #1, z[2]-> #2}) & @@ Z` ? That would work, but I think it would be an inefficient solution, for something that needs to be used tens of thousands of times. And again it bothers me that if the values of `z[i]` were changed, then this workaround would fail. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider asking your future questions at the [dedicated StackExchange site for *Mathematica*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions).
Your questions will be much less likely to become tumbleweeds and may be viewed by many experts.

---

You can inject the value of `a` into the body of both `Function` and `SetDelayed` using `With`:

```
With[{body = a},
 F[Z_] := body & @@ Z
]
```

Check the definition:

```
Definition[F]
```

> ```
> F[Z$_] := ({#1 #2, #2^2} &) @@ Z$
> ```

You'll notice `Z` has become `Z$` due to [automatic renaming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20776/121) within nested scoping constructs but the behavior is the same.

---

In the comments you said:

> And again it bothers me that if the values of `z[i]` were changed, then this workaround would fail.

While this should not be a problem *after* `F[Z_]` is defined as above, if you wish to protect the replacement done for `a` you could use Formal Symbols instead of `z`.  These are entered with e.g. <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$z`<kbd>Esc</kbd> for Formal z.  Formal Symbols have the attribute Protected and exist specifically to avoid such conflicts as this.

This looks much better in a Notebook than it does here:

```
f = {\[FormalZ][1] \[FormalZ][2], \[FormalZ][2]^2};
a = f /. {\[FormalZ][1] -> #1, \[FormalZ][2] -> #2};
```

Another approach is to do the replacements inside a `Hold` expression, and protect the rules themselves from evaluation by using `Unevaluated`:

```
ClearAll[f, z, a, F, Z]

z[2] = "Fail!";

f = Hold[{z[1] z[2], z[2]^2}];
a = f /. Unevaluated[{z[1] -> #1, z[2] -> #2}] // ReleaseHold;

With[{body = a},
 F[Z_] := body & @@ Z
]

Definition[F]
```

> ```
> F[Z$_] := ({#1 #2, #2^2} &) @@ Z$
> ```

Comment: That is perfect, thank you. I've also duly noted the dedicated Mathematica site. I will implement this right now!